# Python webscraping, need input with formatting and how to access information at an array index

Tags: python, html

```
import xml

import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


my_url = 'https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/search/datapage.aspx?Component=Laboratory&CycleBeginYear=2003'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html,'html.parser').findAll('tr')

print(page_soup[2])
```

The above is my code, and my output is the following:

```
<tr>
<td class="text-left">Albumin &amp; Creatinine - Urine</td><td class="text-center">
<a href="/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/L16_C.htm">L16_C Doc</a>
</td><td class="text-center">
<a href="/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/L16_C.XPT">L16_C Data [XPT - 313.2 KB]</a>
</td><td class="text-center">
                    April 2006
                </td>
</tr>
```

I want to take these lines from the array index, which contains a paragraph of html basically, separate out the lines and remove the html tags this is the format I would like it to end up at:

```
Albumin &amp; Creatinine - Urine
/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/L16_C.htm
Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/L16_C.XPT
April 2006
```

I tried using beautiful soup.text but it gets rid of the href, and I don't know how to grab the lines at an array index to separate the information. Is there no way to split the paragraph up line by line, and then handle the formatting I want? I've tried many things but I ran out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated. I might have missed an easy solution, like web scraping the info differently tag by tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to treat the individual table columns differently. For some of them you want just the text, for others you want the hrefs.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup


url = "https://wwwn.cdc.gov/nchs/nhanes/search/datapage.aspx?Component=Laboratory&CycleBeginYear=2003"

response = requests.get(url)
response.raise_for_status()

soup = Soup(response.content, "html.parser")

for row in soup.find("tbody").find_all("tr"):
    name, *files, date = row.find_all("td")
    hrefs = [file.a["href"] for file in files]
    print(name.get_text(strip=True))
    print(*hrefs, sep="\n")
    print(date.get_text(strip=True), "\n")
```

Output:

```
Acrylamide & Glycidamide
/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/L06AGE_C.htm
/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/L06AGE_C.XPT
Updated October 2016 

Albumin & Creatinine - Urine
/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/L16_C.htm
/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/L16_C.XPT
April 2006 

Anti-Mullerian Hormone (AMH) & Inhibin-B (Surplus)
/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/SSAMH_C.htm
/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/SSAMH_C.XPT
January 2015 

...
```

Comment: Hi thanks a lot, I have one entry that came out funny and I am trying to figure out why. It was this one:  Vitamin D
../vitamind/analyticalnote.aspx?h=/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/VID_C.htm&t=VID_C%20Doc
/Nchs/Nhanes/2003-2004/VID_C.XPT
Updated October 2015. The first download link is messed up for some reason, strange because everything else works. I guess I'll have to add an if statement to catch vitamin D and correct it.

Comment: @Erik what's messed up about it? When I navigate to that URL, it works as expected. Do you mean the URL encoding?

Comment: Hi it works now I am running into a different problem but it is related to the problem I had before. I am trying to use the htm and xpt names to download the web page, my problem is that it downloads it as an html file instead of downloading the website as it is displayed when I click on the hyperlink. This is the code that I wrote to try and do it:     gov_website = 'https://wwwn.cdc.gov/'
gov_website = gov_website + chemicalArray[1].doc_file

response = urllib.request.urlopen(gov_website)
content = response.read()

f = open('chemical.xml','wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()